# Merge [enigmatic] and [enigmatic-puzzle] tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, synonym-request

The title says it all. I don't even think I have to explain.
[enigmatic-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enigmatic-puzzle) [enigmatic](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enigmatic)

While we're at it, also merge [music](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music) and [song](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/song)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was only one posting using [enigmatic](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enigmatic), and looks to have been unintentional.  I've changed that tag to the proper [enigmatic-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enigmatic-puzzle).

Similarly, [song](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/song) was used only once and probably should have been [music](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music) all along. I've changed that puzzle to now use the [music](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music) tag.

The no longer used tags will be cleaned up automatically by the system in the next day or so.

Thanks for noticing!